# Is this set linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If the subset $\{ v_1,\ldots ,v_k\}$ is a linearly independent subspace of a vector space, for all nonzero vectors $v$ in that vector space, is the set $\{v+v_1,\ldots,v+v_k \}$ also linearly independent?

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @AndresCaicedo should probably give a counter example to prove that

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\vec{v} = -\vec{v}_1$. It won't be independent

Comment: What conditions on $\vec{v}$ would allow them to be linearly independent?

Comment: @ruler501 When $v\ne -v_i, \forall i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ :-)